# Java: Setting printable width (Pageformat)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, printing, thermal-printer

I am attempting to print from my java application to a receipt printer,
the width of the receipt is 58mm, it seems that the margin is incorrect and printing with a margin of 1 inch on either side. This results in only 3 letters/numbers being printed and not the full line. 
I can print from notepad successfully as I have manually adjusted the margin to 1.97mm on either side which seems to do the trick.

My code is as follows;

```
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex)
        throws PrinterException {

    Font font = new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.PLAIN, 10);
    FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
    int lineHeight = metrics.getHeight();
    if (pageBreaks == null) {
        initTextLines();
        int linesPerPage = (int)(pf.getImageableHeight()/lineHeight);
        int numBreaks = (textLines.length-1)/linesPerPage;
        pageBreaks = new int[numBreaks];
        for (int b=0; b<numBreaks; b++) {
            pageBreaks[b] = (b+1)*linesPerPage;
        }
    }

    if (pageIndex > pageBreaks.length) {
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     * Since we are drawing text we
     */
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setFont(new Font("MONOSPACED", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

    /* Draw each line that is on this page.
     * Increment 'y' position by lineHeight for each line.
     */
    int y = 0;
    int start = (pageIndex == 0) ? 0 : pageBreaks[pageIndex-1];
    int end   = (pageIndex == pageBreaks.length)
            ? textLines.length : pageBreaks[pageIndex];
    for (int line=start; line<end; line++) {
        y += lineHeight;
        g.drawString(textLines[line], 0, y);
    }

    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}
```

I would also be grateful if you could help me align the text to the right hand side of the receipt to keep it uniformed with out other systems, however my main issue is the margin if that is sorted I will be over the moon :)

Thank You!

p.s. I am new to printing from java and have struggled, might have redundant code from copying online sources. I have adjusted the font so it is smaller, that did not help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a workaround to get the desired results, just adding spaces before the text seems to work out well, I have also adjusted the code as follows;

```
public void print() throws PrintException, IOException {
    String defaultPrinter =
            PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().getName();
    System.out.println("Default printer: " + defaultPrinter);
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(printableAmounts.getBytes("UTF8"));

    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    pras.add(new Copies(1));

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    PrintJobWatcher pjw = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
    job.print(doc, pras);
    pjw.waitForDone();
    is.close();
}
```

Seems to be a temporary solution but if nothing else comes up it will become permanent.